# Robot class do not works in IE for the file upload scenario

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I came across this situation
I have a file upload scenario ..here i can not use the sendKeys approach to send the absolute path of the file as there is no input element ,i have only a 'browse' button to select the file from the local folder

so to handle this i use the robot class and the below logic after clicking the 'browser' button using selenium webdriver:

```
StringSelection sc = new StringSelection(file);                 >>file is the one to upload
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(sc, null);
try {
        Robot robot= new Robot();
        robot.delay(3000);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         robot.delay(2000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);    
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        robot.delay(3000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

   }
```

This works very well in chrome and in firefox...but not in Internet Explorer 11
In IE the model dialogue opens ,but it is not pasting the path of the file which is suppose to be uploaded
Is any one facing this issue in IE
Do we have to do anything extra to do this in IE
Please let me know

Thanks,
Musaffir

Comment: I am also having this issue . can you please share the solution here if you have found one back then?

Answer (score 0):

Determines whether to require that the IE window have focus before performing any user interaction operations (mouse or keyboard events). This capability is false by default, but delivers much more accurate native events interactions.

Set Capabilty type like below.it's working for me.

capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", false);